# TurtleBot Kinect object recognition package

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, ros-electric, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use Kinect to recognize 2 objects (book, table), 2 people (adult and child), and 2 postures (stand or sit).

I am confused about OpenCV, OpenNI, PCL, TOD and many things like that. Do I need all of them or just one of them?

Any suggestion for a quick, simple vision package?

In the video "Introducing TurtleBot" in official website, it shows Skeleton Tracking, but what software are they using?

Thank you very much indeed for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57703/turtlebot-kinect-object-recognition-package/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-12**:
Take a look at this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/72511/any-ros-node-for-people-legs-tracking.  Maybe http://wiki.ros.org/people_tracker is (part of) what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenNI and NITE provides people skeleton detection & tracking using the Kinect, but it requires a static background and when your robot moves, it may fail in tracking. You can find samples in [NITE official site](http://www.primesense.com/solutions/nite-middleware/) and [OpenNI official site](http://www.openni.org/)

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
Im trying to accomplish people detection, but ive been unable to find a stack that does it, do you know any?  And in your answer to i need NITE and OpenNi or can i use only one, to accomplish detection?

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-09-12**:
Checkout this: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-23**:
Its really good thanks, did you manage to make it work? Because right now I'm unable to make it work.  And I would really appreciate some help, thanks.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-25**:
@K Chen does it work with a moving camera? or only with a camera that is still?

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-11-27**:
@ctguell it works with a pre-provided camera matrix estimation, so if your camera is moving, you should update the parameters accordingly to make it working

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many ways to detect an object ,but first you need to make an object model for your object ,then try to make the detection using roboearth detector as an example

---

Originally posted by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) with karma: 238 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-17**:
Does roboearth detector work when things are moving? Or it also requires a static background?

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-18**:
It requires a static one.